# Android swipe views with next views on screen

Tags: android, layout

I've already done swipe views with tab, but not with next view appearing in the edge of screen.
Here is an example about what I'm talking about:

[image]

The current view will appear in the center (smaller than screen), next views will appear in the edge of screen, a little bit smaller than the current screen.

Does anyone have any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an library that's very close to what I was looking for:
https://code.google.com/p/carousel-layout-android/

I hope it can help others.